# check for valid user input string and read the string with spaces using scanner in java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am getting user input for the string variable street and trying to check whether it contains only strings and no special characters. And then I am assigning it to a string variable "street". But when the user types, for example "La Jolla" it considers only "La" and ignores "Jolla". How should I modify the code so that it checks for valid input string and also considers space and assigns street variable with "La Jolla"  and also if the street name is just "Montclair" without any more words

```
System.out.println("Please enter the street name>> " );
while(!sc.hasNext("[a-zA-Z]+")){
System.out.println("Please enter a valid street name>> " );
sc.next();
}
String street = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: You need to read the entire line. Use `sc.nextLine()` instead of `sc.next()` in your loop . Also check `sc.hasNextLine()` .

Comment: @TheLostMind: Thank you for the reply. But sc.hasNextLine() doesn't check if the input is a valid string, isn't it?

Comment: No it doesn't. But it will check if you have a line in the std input stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `hasNext("[a-zA-Z]+")` only checks if there is a token matching your expression, not if an entire line is available.
- `next()` gets the next token from the scanner, not next line.
- No real use for `Scanner` in this scenario.

This will work:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  // Optionally add a charset as 2nd parameter.
String street;
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid street name>> " );
    try {
        String line = r.readLine();
        // Accept a line with alphabetic characters delimited with space.
        if (line.matches("[A-Za-z ]+$")) {
            street = line;
            break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle broken input stream here.
        street = "";
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(street);
```

Answer (score 0):

sc.next() finds and returns the next complete token from  the current scanner 'sc'.

Scanner has a method nextLine() which advances the scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.
You need to use nextLine() in your case , so you  can get past the interval.

Comment: You mean if I change the code as follows, it will check whether input is a valid string and reads entire input with spaces?System.out.println("Please enter the street name>> " );
while(!sc.hasNext("[a-zA-Z]+")){
System.out.println("Please enter a valid street name>> " );
sc.nextLine();
}
String street = sc.nextLine();

Comment: basically it will skip the entire thing  + spaces then  return what is skipped. What you have written  should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the street name>> ");
    String street = sc.nextLine();

    while (!isAlphabet(street)) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid street name>> ");
        street = sc.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(street);
    sc.close();
}

public static boolean isAlphabet(String s) {
    return s.matches("[a-z A-Z]+");
}
```

**Output**

```
>     Please enter the street name>> 
>     La Jolla%
>     Please enter a valid street name>> 
>     La Jolla
>     La Jolla
```